Is it possible to remove/disable News templates in SharePoint Online
I have a requirement and what i'm after is for users to be able to create a news post but i want them to use a specific template only and not to be able to use any of the other templates from Microsoft.
Is this possible and what are my options
Thanks
See image below


Microsoft currently does not provide a way to remove or disable the built-in news templates in SharePoint Online. You cannot edit these built-in templates. If you edit and save these templates, they will be added under “Saved to this site,” which is a separate menu.
However, there is a workaround suggested by the community. You can make your custom template the default template. This way, when a user selects a new page, they are taken to the "Saved to this site" tab.
Please note that these are general steps and the exact process may vary depending on your organization's and Microsoft's specific policies. I would recommend that you consult the official Microsoft documentation or contact Microsoft support for more precise guidance.

Thanks Eduardo for the email.
You suggested there is a workaround to make a custom template a default template. Can you kindly please forward a link orresources to this if possible
